# Set date in English but leave region untouched

Tags: settings, language-support

I am living in Belgium, Flanders and my setup of Ubuntu is in English.
Though, my date and days are in Dutch.
Is there a way to set it in English also, but leave my region untouched?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty easy to do!
First, you gotta open a terminal and type `locale`. There will be a screen that displays a bunch of language related information. Important is the variable `LC_TIME`. You can take the following command to change it to the US date format:

`sudo update-locale LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"`

Then log out and in again and everything should be fine!

Hope that helped!

Comment: Almost!
When I log off or restart my PC it is in English, but the moment I login it is in Dutch again.
If I check /etc/default/locale, LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8". So, that is okay.
But I think there is also a local file in my user profile
I will try to perform a locate in a terminal to find an other config file as well.

Comment: I had to change it in Settings as well.
So I put in en_GB as we in Europe use the metric system and the DDMMYY format
But issue is solved.

Thanks for shining your light on this ;-) !